# Superset Blank Dataset field

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-superset

Currently in my company we using a couple of software for our Kpi,

- Nifi
- Elasticsearch 1.3.2
- Superset 7.16.2

Since i have updated the elasticsearch database to 7.16.2 i have a problem in superset, i'm not able to see any index when i would like to add a new dataset the field is blank but when i watch the logs i can see the indexes. When i would like to sync the old dataset i have this message

I'm using the last version of elasticsearch-dbapi.

I'm not sure that the problem come from the elastic search upgrade but it's strange than superset ui not display our indexes.

Do you have already the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend opening a detailed Github issue in the Apache Superset repo:

https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/new?assignees=&labels=%23bug&template=bug_report.md

Stack Overflow is better utilized for questions and answers!